# Why running time of better algorithm code is more than primitive algorithm code?

Tags: python

Problem description : Write a function that takes in a non-empty array of integers that are sorted in ascending order and returns a new array of the same length with the squares of the original integers also sorted in ascending order.

I have wrote two Python functions to solve the problem. One is 'sortedSquaredArrayNormal' and another called 'sortedSquaredArrayBetter'. First one has O(nlogn) time complexity and second function has O(n) time complexity I guess. I have also written third function 'test_runtime_compare' that prints each function run time. Below is my code:

```
import random
import time

def sortedSquaredArrayNormal(array):
    square_arr = []
    for elem in array:
        square_arr.append(elem*elem)
        
    square_arr.sort()
    return square_arr


def sortedSquaredArrayBetter(array):
    big_index = len(array)-1
    small_index = 0
    output_arr = [0 for elem in array]
    
    # elements of bigger indices inserted first in output array
    for idx in range(len(array)-1, -1, -1):
        small_elem = array[small_index]
        big_elem = array[big_index]
        if(abs(small_elem) > abs(big_elem)):
            output_arr[idx] =  small_elem * small_elem
            small_index += 1 # small index is shifted 1 position to right
        else:
            output_arr[idx] = big_elem * big_elem
            big_index -= 1 # big index is shifted 1 position to left 
            
    return output_arr

def test_runtime_compare():
    new_arr = [random.randrange(-100, 100) for i in range(100000)]
    new_arr.sort()
    initial = time.time()
    dummy = sortedSquaredArrayNormal(new_arr)
    final  = time.time()
    normal_time = final - initial
    print('Normal time: {}'.format(normal_time))

    time.sleep(5)

    initial = time.time()
    new = sortedSquaredArrayBetter(new_arr)
    final = time.time()
    better_time = final - initial
    print('Better time: {}'.format(better_time))

test_runtime_compare()
```

I got the output:

Normal time: 0.03777050971984863
Better time: 0.11590099334716797

I was expecting 'better time' to be smaller than 'normal time'. But every time I run the code in my machine with larger input array I get 'normal time' less than 'better time'. I can't find the cause. Can anyone help me to understand the cause? Do I have any mistake in complexity analysis?

Comment: Time complexity is not directly convertible into runtime, runtime depends on more factors than go into calculating time complexity.

Comment: `sort` is a built-in function, hence it will be faster than Python code.

Comment: Big-O time complexity is asymptotic only. If you increase the size of your test case, you should see the better one become faster eventually. But O(n log n) is pretty close to O(n) in practice, because the logarithm grows slowly. So maybe you need a very big computer before you see the theoretically faster algorithm become faster in practice.

Comment: to elaborate more, most, if not all, builtins are written in C and compiled (and so are much faster than "normal" Python code) .. a practical reason for this is that creating intermediate Python objects is more expensive, often defeating apparent benchmarks like this .. however, there's no need to sort as the squares of values ordered by size will have the same order!

Comment: Not directly related, but measuring time is a complex operation. Do not blindly trust a single run calling `time` at beginning and end, but always use the `timeit` module which specifically targets that.

Comment: Every year new students learn about big-O notation and every year they painfully have to learn that "better big-O" does not always translate into better performance in real-world use cases.

Answer (score 0):

> take in non-empty array of integers that are sorted in ascending order
> and returns a new array of the same length with the squares of the
> original integers also sorted in ascending order.

That sounds like a very trivial issue, were it not for negative numbers.

For example, for [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3], you would have to sort [9,4,1,0,1,4,9].
The order of the squared numbers is very predictable, hence you found an algorithm that does it in O(n).

But maybe the built-in algorithm for sort is also very good at sorting these kinds of very monotone sequences, so it can also do it in O(n) instead of O(n * log(n)), which is for completely random sequences.